# Set an image as background in Open GL

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

I want to achieve the following result in OpenGL (and C++): I have  a plot I want to use as background of an animation and I want it to be fix when some points move on its surface. 
For example (see the image): I want  to calculate the level plot of 3 variables function (black and white in the photo), I want to set it as background and show an animation of points moving on the surface (red points in the photo).
What is the best method to achieve it and have good performances?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the background image as a file?

Comment: I see ten circles, ten discs and five points in this image. Today's graphics hardware manages millions of polygons easily. Is there any reason at all you're concerned with performance?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to draw your background image as a texture on a quad behind the other points (e.g., points at Z=0.1, quad at Z=0.2). Since you (presumably) don't want the quad scaled compared to the points, you probably want to use an orthographic projection, not perspective.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which version of OpenGL you are using.

If you are using SDL and OpenGL 2.x, it is very easy, but if you are using something like GLFW and OpenGL 3.x, it will be quite hard.

But this is how you would do it with SDL and OpenGL 2.1(not all code is included, you will have to write some of it yourself):

```
void plot(SDL_Surface *surf, int x, int y, int r, int g, int b)
{
    int color = SDL_MapRGB(surf->format, r, g, b);
    Uint32 *framebuffer = (Uint32*) surf->pixels;
    framebuffer[y * surf->w + x] = color;
}

int main()
{
    /* set up SDL and OpenGL */
    SDL_Surface *img = SDL_LoadBMP("base_background.bmp");

    /* plot functions like this: */
    plot(img, x, f(x), 255, 0, 0); // example colours

    /* create an OpenGL surface(code can be found on google easily) */ 
    GLuint tex = create_GL_texture(img);

    /* draw it like you would normally */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        ...
    glEnd(); 

    return 0;
}
```

For OpenGL 3.x, it is a bit harder. You can find tutorials [here](http://opengl-tutorial.com).